# How to activate Rstudio Viewer pane for rmarkdown xaringan slide?

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, xaringan

Hi whenever I **knit** `xaringan` slide rmd file in `rmarkdown`, it shows up in **a separate window** instead of **Viewer inside rstudio**. Is there any way to make rstudio Viewer properly working? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the menu: `Tools -> Global Options -> R Markdown -> Show output preview in [Viewer Pane]`.

Or use [`xaringan::inf_mr()`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan-preview.html).